# Meta-refresh based on Link Field

Tags: entities, redirection, meta-tags

I have a custom content type that contains a Link field. I want to add a [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to every page of that content type that will redirect to the contents of the link field after a fixed number of seconds. (I also have a link/button that will open the target of the link, but I want to redirect automatically after a few seconds as well.) I am a bit confused about the number of meta modules available - which module or combination of modules can be used to achieve this, preferably without hacking any of the core or additional modules?

Comment: which of the existing many modules have you tried on your website?

Comment: you could easily do it in a preprocess hook for the content type, checking the link value then using the drupal_add_html_head function to add the redirect meta tag.